# Efficiently applying custom functions to groups in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe, pandas-groupby

This question is about efficiently applying a custom function on logical groups of rows in a Pandas dataframe, which share a value in some column.

Consider the following example of a dataframe:

```
sID = [1,1,1,2,4,4,5,5,5]
data = np.random.randn(len(sID))
dates = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', periods=len(sID))

mydf = pd.DataFrame({"subject_id":sID, "data":data, "date":dates})
mydf['date'][5] += pd.Timedelta('2 days')
```

which looks like:

```
       data       date  subject_id
0  0.168150 2018-01-01           1
1 -0.484301 2018-01-02           1
2 -0.522980 2018-01-03           1
3 -0.724524 2018-01-04           2
4  0.563453 2018-01-05           4
5  0.439059 2018-01-08           4
6 -1.902182 2018-01-07           5
7 -1.433561 2018-01-08           5
8  0.586191 2018-01-09           5
```

Imagine that for each `subject_id`, we want to subtract from each date the first date encountered for this subject_id. Storing the result in a new column "days_elapsed", the result will look like this:

```
       data       date  subject_id  days_elapsed
0  0.168150 2018-01-01           1             0
1 -0.484301 2018-01-02           1             1
2 -0.522980 2018-01-03           1             2
3 -0.724524 2018-01-04           2             0
4  0.563453 2018-01-05           4             0
5  0.439059 2018-01-08           4             3
6 -1.902182 2018-01-07           5             0
7 -1.433561 2018-01-08           5             1
8  0.586191 2018-01-09           5             2
```

One natural way of doing this is by using `groupby` and `apply`:

```
g_df = mydf.groupby('subject_id')
mydf.loc[:, "days_elapsed"] = g_df["date"].apply(lambda x: x - x.iloc[0]).astype('timedelta64[D]').astype(int)
```

However, if the number of groups (subject IDs) is big (e.g. 10^4), and let's say only 10 times smaller than the length of the dataframe, this very simple operation is really slow.

**Is there any faster method?**

---

PS: I have also tried setting the index to `subject_id` and then using the following list comprehension:

```
def get_first(series, ind):
    "Return the first row in a group within a series which (group) potentially can span multiple rows and corresponds to a given index"
    group = series.loc[ind]

    if hasattr(group, 'iloc'):
        return group.iloc[0]
    else: # this is for indices with a single element
        return group

hind_df = mydf.set_index('subject_id')
A = pd.concat([hind_df["date"].loc[ind] - get_first(hind_df["date"], ind) for ind in np.unique(hind_df.index)])
```

However, it's even slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy` + `transform` with `first`. This should be more efficient as it avoids expensive `lambda` function calls.

You may also see a performance improvement by working with the NumPy array via [`pd.Series.values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html):

```
first = df.groupby('subject_id')['date'].transform('first').values

df['days_elapsed'] = (df['date'].values - first).astype('timedelta64[D]').astype(int)

print(df)

   subject_id      data       date  days_elapsed
0           1  1.079472 2018-01-01             0
1           1 -0.197255 2018-01-02             1
2           1 -0.687764 2018-01-03             2
3           2  0.023771 2018-01-04             0
4           4 -0.538191 2018-01-05             0
5           4  1.479294 2018-01-08             3
6           5 -1.993196 2018-01-07             0
7           5 -2.111831 2018-01-08             1
8           5 -0.934775 2018-01-09             2
```

Comment: The performance improvement is insane: from 33 sec to 0.05 sec, i.e. 660x !
So from this may I conclude that "custom" functions should be avoided at all costs and that one always has to use pandas building blocks when applying functions to groups?

Comment: @Ataxias, Indeed, you see a large improvement. Using NumPy isn't *always* the best answer. You have to know exactly what you're doing and it helps to know some NumPy to understand the pitfalls. For example, NumPy doesn't deal with null values as cleanly as Pandas.

Comment: Thanks! In this case, using the numpy arrays provides quite a benefit, though: run time without it is 5.89 sec, which in relative terms is more than 100x slower!

Answer (score 1):

```
mydf['days_elapsed'] = (mydf['date'] - mydf.groupby(['subject_id'])['date'].transform('min')).dt.days
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The performance improvement in this case was great: 5.2x (from 33 sec to  6.34 sec). Using the function `first` instead of `min` further reduces the time to 5.89 sec, and `pd.Series.values` further reduces this to 0.05 sec, as suggested by [jpp's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52564105/4055338)